# Why do I get a SQL syntax error when I try to insert values into a table with a column named "index"?

Tags: mysql, perl, insert, blob

I am attempting to insert a binary file (JPG image) in to a **MySQL** database using perl

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `sku` CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    `index` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `main` BLOB NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

Perl:

```
$dbh_local = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db;host=127.0.0.1;mysql_enable_utf8=1", "XXX", "XXX", {'RaiseError' => 1, 'mysql_auto_reconnect' => 1});

open IMAGE, "c:/image.jpg" or die $!;
    while(read IMAGE, $buff, 1024) {
        $image .= $buff;
    }
close(IMAGE);

my $sku = 'VM1000032999';
my $index = 1;

$query = "INSERT INTO images (sku,index,main) values (?,?,?)";
$sth = $dbh_local->prepare($query);
$sth->bind_param(1,$sku);
$sth->bind_param(2,$index);
$sth->bind_param(3,$image, DBI::SQL_BLOB);
$sth->execute();        
$sth->finish();
```

However I am getting this error:

```
"DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index,main) values ('VM1000032999','1','????\0►JFIF\0☺☺☺\0H\0H\0\0??\0?\0♠♦♣♠♣♦♠' at line 1 at ...."
```

Any ideas? I have tried several variations, all giving the same error.

Comment: index is a reserved word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: You can't call a column index as its a reserved word. It works in the create table as its quoted. Either always quote it or better still pick a word which isn't reserved

Comment: `index` is a mysql keyword.  It's best not to use keywords as field names, but if you do, you need to escape them like you did in the create table statement.

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You are using the reserved word `index` in your `INSERT INTO`-statement. The use of reserved words as identifiers is [only permitted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) with quotes as described in [Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).

Change `index` to `` `index` `` in your `INSERT INTO` statement.

I do not recommend to use reserved words in your table.